# How to write SQL query that returns the proportion of total weekly sales made on each day of the week

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to write SQL query that returns the proportion of total weekly sales made on each day of the week. A week is considered to be Monday to Sunday.
For Oracle or SQL server DB.

[image]

Thanks in Advance
Venkatesh

Comment: By proportion do you mean the percentage?

Comment: Data in your image seems a report, not a table, what is the table schema?

Comment: Hi,   Yes percentage and yes it is a report..please assume Item_1 + Item_2 as one column i.e. total sales.  Table name is (db.sales)

Answer (score 2):

I've set up an example with the next data:

> ```
> declare @sales table (item_id int, date_sale datetime, items int);
> insert into @sales values
> (1, '20170101', 5),
> (1, '20170101', 6),
> (1, '20170102', 7),
> (1, '20170102', 4),
> (1, '20170104', 2),
> (1, '20170104', 2),
> (1, '20170105', 1),
> (1, '20170105', 6),
> (1, '20170106', 7),
> (1, '20170107', 5),
> (1, '20170107', 4),
> (1, '20170108', 3),
> (1, '20170108', 2),
> (1, '20170109', 2),
> (1, '20170109', 1),
> (1, '20170110', 2),
> (1, '20170110', 2),
> (1, '20170111', 1);
> ```

Sum the daily items and use a subquery to calculate week total and percentage.

> ```
> select     s2.item_id, s2.date_sale, sum(s2.items) as total_items, 
>            (select sum(s.items)
>             from @sales s
>             where s.item_id = s2.item_id
>             and   datepart(wk, s.date_sale) = datepart(wk, s2.date_sale)
>             group by s.item_id, datepart(wk, s.date_sale)) total_week,
>            (sum(s2.items) * 100.0 / (select sum(s.items)
>                                      from @sales s
>                                      where s.item_id = s2.item_id
>                                      and   datepart(wk, s.date_sale) = datepart(wk, s2.date_sale)
>                                      group by s.item_id, datepart(wk, s.date_sale))) as percentage
> from       @sales s2
> group by   s2.item_id, s2.date_sale;
> ```

This is the final result:

> ```
> item_id | date_sale           | total_items | total_week | percentage     
> ------: | :------------------ | ----------: | ---------: | :--------------
>       1 | 01/01/2017 00:00:00 |          11 |         49 | 22.448979591836
>       1 | 02/01/2017 00:00:00 |          11 |         49 | 22.448979591836
>       1 | 04/01/2017 00:00:00 |           4 |         49 | 8.163265306122 
>       1 | 05/01/2017 00:00:00 |           7 |         49 | 14.285714285714
>       1 | 06/01/2017 00:00:00 |           7 |         49 | 14.285714285714
>       1 | 07/01/2017 00:00:00 |           9 |         49 | 18.367346938775
>       1 | 08/01/2017 00:00:00 |           5 |         13 | 38.461538461538
>       1 | 09/01/2017 00:00:00 |           3 |         13 | 23.076923076923
>       1 | 10/01/2017 00:00:00 |           4 |         13 | 30.769230769230
>       1 | 11/01/2017 00:00:00 |           1 |         13 | 7.692307692307
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=db997f4c5921c4add9a3c21198c75abe)*

Answer (score 0):

try this, you'll have to complete the script though

```
    select 
      sum ...,  iif(datepart(dw,sales_date)=1,datepart(week,sales_date)-1,datepart(week,sales_date)) [WeekNo]
      from
    sales
    group by 
    iif(datepart(dw,sales_date)=1,datepart(week,sales_date)-1,datepart(week,sales_date))
```

> test and explanation

```
declare @date date = '26-march-2017'

select datepart(week,@date) [sqlweek], -- official sqlweek
iif(datepart(dw,@date)=1,7,datepart(dw,@date)-1) [DayofWeekM-S], -- day of the week being Monday - Sunday (7)
iif(datepart(dw,@date)=1,datepart(week,@date)-1,datepart(week,@date)) [NewWeek]   -- if day falls on a sunday then -1 week, sql week begins from Sunday
```